# Looping through ACF in custom post types using functions in php to display the values in page. foreach quits working when placed in the function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, foreach, shortcode

I created this code to display the location from ACF that matches part of the URL and it works as expected.

```
<?php

$myurl= htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$myexplodes = ( explode ('/', $myurl) ); 
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'     => 'my_vars',
));


if( $posts ){   
    foreach( $posts as $post ){ 
        $value = get_field( "location" );
            //echo get_field( "location" );
        if( $value == $myexplodes[1]) {
            echo '<h1>' . $value . ' :this is location</h1>';

        } 
        else {
        }
    } 
} 

?>
```

But when I try to place this code into a function nothing is displayed when I call it.

```
function local (){
    if( $posts ){   
        foreach( $posts as $post ){ 
            $value = get_field( "location" );
            //echo get_field( "location" );
            if( $value == $myexplodes[1]) {
                echo '<h1>' . $value . ' :this is location</h1>';

            } 
            else {
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

I suspected that it is a scope problem with the vars but I have tried to make the vars global but had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The first one probably works because $post is a WordPress global variable, so I advise to use another variable name in your foreach.

For the thing that you want to do you should use also the post id in the get_field function call:

```
$value = get_field( "location", $article->ID );
```

Comment: I have been looking into this. I understand the get_field part but could you elaborate on the global variable being $post?

Comment: Wordpress uses a global variable called $post and this might interfere in your foreach. Instead of foreach( $posts as $post ) use foreach( $articles as $article )